# Boot Ubuntu without disk nfs + pxe

Tags: boot, disk, nfs, pxe

I want to boot from pxe, dhcp -> pxelinux.0 -> as I understand then, you need the kernel (the question you need to prepare or from the installation CD to take and norms)

```
 LABEL Ubuntu linux Live Boot
KERNEL ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz
```

->the next step I want to nfs mount as a hard drive.
something similar, but as correct

```
APPEND root=/dev/nfs boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/ubuntu ip=192.168.0.5:192.168.0.1:192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0 initrd=ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz
```

->and as I understand this, fstab should see my nfs and there should be a file system
->I think to try to install to the hard drive and copy dd
->who did? or wrong? tell us step by step, or stage as should all work..saw something like iscs, but why should anyone have nfs support in the kernel,right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I PXE boot:

```
LABEL Ubuntu
Menu label Ubuntu 
kernel images/ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz.efi
append boot=casper vga=normal locale=de_de netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.178.33:/volume1/TFTP/boot/images/ubuntu rw initrd=images/ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz persistent
```

Look into to scripts directory cor casper and casper-helpers script and you see what they do.